# Angular Mocks and Jasmine - "Argument 'fn' is not a function, got Object" error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, coffeescript, jasmine

I have an issue with unit testing using Angular (with Angular-Mocks), Jasmine and CoffeeScript.

Specifically, this code breaks:

```
'use strict'

describe 'sample suite', ->

    beforeEach inject(($rootScope, $compile) ->
        scope = $rootScope.$new()
    )

    it 'should be true', ->
        expect('foo').toBe('foo')
```

resulting in Angular `debug.html:37 Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'fn' is not a function, got Object` error.

This, however does work:

```
'use strict'

describe 'sample suite', ->

    beforeEach ->
        sample = 'test'

    it 'should be true', ->
        expect('foo').toBe('foo')
```

Which means using the syntax with global `inject()` angular-mocks method doesn't work with CoffeeScript compiler properly.

Ending `beforeEach` block with `return` doesn't work, sadly.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Please check the following question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17601744/using-karma-runner-with-angularjs-jasmine-coffescript.

Comment: @TomePejoski Do you mean not using wildcards? Doesn't help, I suppose the issue lies somewhere between Karma and the Jasmine adapter.

Comment: No, [it does not](http://plnkr.co/edit/X76cMs5b1KO5jMJ32tsR?p=preview). Your testing code obviously differs from the one you've posted. Please, provide [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This most likely happens due to the error in your Angular app (improper `config` block or so).

Answer (score 0):

If you look at your two codes working and not working you will notice the big difference

In the first block `beforeEach` accepts as parameter the `inject` while in working you pass as argument an anonymous function `beforeEach ->`
that's why you get the error `Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'fn' is not a function, got Object`

```
'use strict'

describe 'sample suite', ->

  beforeEach ->
    inject ($rootScope, $compile) ->
      scope = $rootScope.$new()


  it 'should be true', ->
    expect('foo').toBe('foo')
```

Comment: Yes, there is a difference, and no, `inject` accepts both usages, this isn't the problem here.

Comment: I was not talking about `inject`, I was talking about `beforeEach` which requires function and you execute it with object (inject)

Comment: `inject()` returns a wrapper function that can be called (by beforeEach or it). This is expected behaviour. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40626775/angular-mocks-and-jasmine-argument-fn-is-not-a-function-got-object-error/40742174?noredirect=1#comment68773711_40626775

Comment: Right, my bad, other than that from top of my head I can think of bad dependency injection i.e. `.factory('myFactory', 'injection', function(injection){})` instead of array notation `.factory('myFactory', ['injection', function(injection){}])`